# Ошибка при push из-за большого файла в Git Bash

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-bash

На удалённом сервере я сделал коммит для одного файла большого размера. И теперь при попытке сделать push для всех файлов, пишет что невозможно сделать. В итоге ни один файл не отправляется на Git. Я пробовал несколько вариантов, теперь они показывают что такого файла нет в директории, хоть при повторном push, он все равно обращает на него внимание. Что-то можно сделать в данной ситуации???

```
[...]$ git rm nohup.out
fatal: pathspec 'nohup.out' did not match any files
[...]$ git rm --cached nohup.out
fatal: pathspec 'nohup.out' did not match any files


    Total 14 (delta 5), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 1 local object.
remote: error: Trace: bbbdbae33a14d503b2538f5e0ada9cfb91e3d02fd737562912a0b9c742a6b913
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File Laboratory-work-7/nohup.out is 2945.95 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

Comment: В официальной документации `github` есть отдельный раздел по поводу больших файлов, почитайте: [ссылка](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не публикуйте тексты ошибок картинками. Вместо этого вы можете поместить их прямо в вопрос, используя блоки кода.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков - эта LFS почти бесполезная из-за своих ограничений по размеру и трафику.

Comment: Надо чтобы этого файла не было среди коммитов в истории. Отредактируйте тот комит, где был добавлен этот файл.

Comment: @user7860670 как это сделать?

Comment: Делайте checkout этого коммита, удаляете файл и делаете `git add -A` && `git commit --amend` А потом делайте rebase последующих коммитов на этот - получится история без того файла.